# Getting started with 3-tier architecture in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, 3-tier

I recently started developing a project in 3-Tier architecture, with a BLL, DAL, and Presentation layers. The references I used were sample 3-tier applications off the net, and all of them differ from each other. So, now i am confused which one is the correct 3-tier.

Could you please be kind enough, to point to a proper tutorials or book, which is following the correct 3-tier architecture, so that I could follow it.

Answer (score 1):

look at this article
[article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validating-with-a-service-layer-vb)

in 3 tier architecture there are:

1. DAL Repository classes
2. BLL Services classes
3. PL  Controllers classes

Comment: but, this is ASP.net, I need in VB.Net

Comment: ASP.NET this is technology for create web application it's in-depend on C# or VB language, what do you mean about VB.NET?

Comment: I am developing a desktop application on VB, not c#. Web and Desktop application are different so, I dont think the article will provide me with enough guidance

Comment: DAL and BLL layer you could implement the same as in article, but presentation you should look at MVP pattern for Win forms application and MVVM for WPF application

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was learning about architecture of .NET applications in C# language. It is normaly then 3-layer (layer and tier has other meaning) aplications are different. I think the best theory you get from book Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns by Scott Millet. Scott describes BLL, DAL and the most frequently used patterns on these layers. When you start with developing .NET applications I recommend you learn about ActiveRecord pattern that is easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

3-tiered/layered architecture is a guideline (or [software design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture)), therefore you will find implementations of the guideline will vary depending on interpretation, specific application use cases/requirements and frameworks that are available to the developer. This is even the case within the context of a single language, such as vb.net. It would be wrong to assume there is one "correct" implementation, but some are better than others.

Whilst very detailed and not providing direct code samples, the [Microsoft Patterns and Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921345.aspx) are a good reference for [architecting .net applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650706.aspx). There is an in-depth discussion of layering strategies and choosing the right one for your scenario here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx. It may help reveal that out of the samples you already have, one is *better* for your use case.